# jquery function call

Tags: jquery, function

I bound the blur function to a text box having class name 'qtyToPick'. Now I want to call the same blur function if I change checked property of a check box having class 'chkSelect'.

How can i do it ?

```
$('.qtyToPick').live('blur', function() {
    //  Code here
});
```

Comment: @SLaks. Was there any mistakes in my qustion ?

Comment: You should format code by indenting it with four spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Define the function separately, and bind it to the appropriate events for the appropriate elements:

```
var theFunc = function() { /* Code here */ };

$( '.qtyToPick' ).live( 'blur', theFunc );
$( '.chkSelect' ).live( 'change', theFunc );
```

Comment: $('#chkSelect').change(function() {
  $('.qtyToPick').blur();
});

Comment: I think trigger handler might be more appropriate in this case if you're taking that route.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#chkSelect').change(function() {

   $('.qtyToPick').blur();

});
```